# Let X be the number of times you and your friend get the same outcome. Then X is distributed as

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

You and your friend have a fair coin each. Both of you toss the coins simultaneously, record the outcomes, and repeat the process, for a total of $n$ times. Let $X$ be the number of times you and your friend get the same outcome. Then $X$ is distributed as

SELECT ALL CORRECT OPTIONS

(a) $Binom(n,1/2)$

(b) $Geom(1/2)$

(c) $Binom(n,3/4)$

(d) $Binom(n,1/4)$

I thought the answer as $Binom(n,1/2)$ .. Since getting the same number of outcome is equiprobable. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Hamed I thought as $Binom(n,1/2)$ .. Since getting same number of outcome is equiprobable. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I suggest you include your thoughts inside the body of the question, explain your reasoning and then ask what part of the question is confusing to you. As it is, seems like you're asking us to do your homework for you. That's not what this site is about. We don't do homeworks, we help you do it yourself.

Comment: You are correct.  Personal observation - there are too many nannies on this forum!

Comment: hi @herbsteinberg , my sincere apologies for not adding the logic behind my answer earlier. Could you please have a look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You and your friend have a fair coin each. Both of you toss the coins
>   simultaneously, record the outcomes, and repeat the process, for a
>   total of $n$ times. Let $X$ be the number of times you and your friend
>   get the same outcome. Then $X$ is distributed as

Suppose that $X$ is random binomial variable. We have $X \sim Bin(n,p)$ which describes the number of successes $k$ in $n$ independent trials.

The question asks that both of toss the same outcome. The sample space for the tosses for both of you are given by

$$\Omega = \{ (H,H), (H,T) ,(T,H), (T,T)\} $$

the outcomes where they are the same is simply

$$E  =\{ (H,H) ,(T,T)\} $$
the probability $p$ is $\frac{2}{4} =\frac{1}{2}$

Then we see that $X \sim Bin(n,\frac{1}{2})$. The geometric distribution is also constructed from independent bernoulli trials, however it is describing until you don't succeed.